# Mark up for defining operations and rules around knowledge?

Tags: sparql, rdf, rule-engine

I have been trying to teach my self RDF and Sparql and I am interested in finding out if there are any extensions or alternative to marking up knowledge  that would let me define rules or operations and then query for knowledge that can be extracted using rules or operations?

For a simple example would I be able to mark up the following and then be able to query asking for the value of c and have it return the value 2 preferably with the rules it used to determine that was the value. Without defining the rules in the query, but by defining the rules in the markup.

```
a = 6
b = 3   
a/b = c
```

---

Edit:
Just extending the description to try and give some more detail about what I am trying to find out.

The specific application I want to try and use this for is taking the information and rules that a program advisers at university currently uses when suggesting what units a student should enroll in and have a computer be able to suggest the units the student should enroll in and why it choose those units and what rules it used in making it's decision.

For example:
I would like to be able to have a collection of information and rules about units, programs, and students, and be able to query the list of units for a student to find what units they can choose to study in the next term.

Units would have:

- a level(first year, second year, ...)
- a study mode (internal, external)
- a location (the city or campus an internal course is offered at)
- a faculty (IT, Engineering)
- possible pre-requisites (student must have completed another unit before starting this unit)
- more complex requirements (students must have a police background check before starting any child care units)

A program would have rules like:

- Core units (list of units that the student must do)
- Elective units (with rules about how many electives can be outside of the programs faculty and how many can be first year subjects)

And a student would have:

- Campus location
- study mode (internal or external)
- Internation student flag
- visa rules (student might need to do a minimum of 3 units internally to keep there visa)

Because there can be different rules for different students, and for different units and for different programs. And these rules are constantly changing it isn't possible to code all the rules into a system. I want to find out if there is a way to store the rules with the unit, program and student information outside of the code for the system so the rules could be maintained separately?

Comment: Ehm SWRL or what do you mean?

Comment: It's not clear what user802599 means by *markup*, thus, we should wait for clarification.